# Polymer replace url, spacing

Tags: javascript, replace, polymer

I would like to replace spacing in my url before change page and create url that I want.
Replace does not work.
My function is like this

```
 handleTap: function(item) {
  var item = this.$.listTypes.itemForElement(item.target);
  var e = item.type;
  e.replace(" ", "-");
  console.log(e);
  window.location.hash = e; }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more reliable ways of building SEO friendly URLS, but here at least is a quick fix that might help you.

2 problems:

- the replace() only replaced the first occurence unless you are using a regular expression.
- replace() does not actually alter the value it's acting on.  You need to apply to result to something like a variable.

Just replace:

```
e.replace(" ", "-");
```

With

```
e = e.replace(/[ ]/g, '-');
```